# How to do voice typing with Whisper AI on Windows?

Tags: windows, whisper, voice-typing

How to do voice typing with Whisper AI on Windows?

Windows built-int voice typing engine is not available in Russian.

All articles I found on Web about Whisper AI are about transcribing audio files.

I am not interested in transcribing audio files, but rather in voice typing.

Any idea how to make it work?